# using return value in class

Tags: c++, class

the header file

```
#ifndef deneme_h
#define deneme_h

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std ;
class A
{
public:
Course ( int code ) ;
int getACode () ;


 private:

    int code   ;

};


class B
{

  public:
    B ( A * a  = NULL) ;
        A     * getA     () ;

 private:

    A     * a   ;
  friend ostream & operator<< ( ostream & out , B & b ) ;
};

#endif
```

the A.cpp

```
#include "deneme.h"
using namespace std ;


A :: A ( int code )
{
    this -> code = code;
} 

int A :: getACode()
{
    return this -> code;
}
```

the B.cpp

```
#include "deneme.h"

using namespace std ;

B::B ( A     * a ) 
    {
        this -> a = new A(223);
        this -> a = a;

    }
A * A::getA     ()  {   return this -> a;}



ostream & operator<< ( ostream & out , B & b ) { out << b.course->getACode();}
```

and the main.cpp

```
#include "deneme.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

Course* c1 = new Course(223) ;

Offering* o1_1 = new  Offering(c1);

cout<< *o1_1;

return 0;
}
```

Hello everyone

I want to ask about this code. The above code works fine and it prints 223. But when I change the operator overloading part in B.cpp

```
 ostream & operator<< ( ostream & out , Offering & offering ) { out << offering.(getCourse() )->getCourseCode();}
```

I get an error. Why does it give error? Can't I use a return value. Thanks for answers.

Comment: I don't understand what change should I do?

Comment: if a function has a return type other than `void` there _must_ be a `return` statement that returns an instance of the return type. So add `return out;` to `operator<<()`.

Comment: you need to add 'return' keyword before out;

Comment: I add return thanks but now I get and different error


         offering.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Offering&)’:
         offering.cpp:18:80: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
         offering.cpp:18:91: error: ‘getCourse’ was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 2):

As already said, you need to return out, I think the line you want is :

```
ostream & operator<< ( ostream & out , Offering & offering ) { out << ( offering.getCourse() )->getCourseCode(); return out; }
```

(I moved a parenthesis)

Comment: Oh, thank you!
but why offering.(getCourse())->getCourseCode(); 
this doesn't work despite I add the return out part

Comment: You want to apply the -> operator on the member so first take the member : offering.getCourse() and then apply the -> operator on the whole statement so : ( offering.getCourse() )-> ...

Comment: And I want to ask one more question if you have time. I add the 223 number in B.cpp

Course* c1 = new Course(223) ;

but I don't want to put it there I want to put it in main but when I don't do I get an error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Following code is incorrect, you are overriding this->a value after assignment `B::B ( A     * a ) 
    {
        this -> a = new A(223);
        this -> a = a;

    }
` So just do this->a = a and in main : `new Offering( new Course(223) )` Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

remove the parentheses around getCourse()

Comment: it works when remove the parantheses but why it works?

Comment: Because the compiler expects a member of the object after operator '.' and not '('.

Answer (score 0):

When used with iostream:

`operator<<` should take its second parameter by const reference (or value if that's trivial).

It should return its first parameter.

so

```
ostream & operator<< ( ostream & out , const B & b ) 
{ 
     return out << b.course->getACode();
} 

ostream & operator<< ( ostream & out , const Offering & offering ) 
{ 
    return out << offering.getCourse()->getCourseCode();
}
```

You can also put `return out` as a separate statement after the other statement in both cases.

Note also that in C++ you do not have to create all your objects with new.